# How to get response from redirect request using flask API in Python?

Tags: flask

I have two containers (docker) running the application and I'm trying to redirect the request from one of the container to another. The container where I'm redirecting from has this code and the 172.17.0.3 is the IP of the second container. I have seen that it can be pinged. In the other container I don't have the else part and no if condition check. When I run a curl request to this container using another client container in the same network **curl http://172.17.0.2:3333?count=100**, it should ideally redirect but I get Internal Server Error as the response. However, when I login to the container 2 and run curl, I get redirected to ... response.

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Greeting (Resource):
    def get(self):
        offload = True
        if offload == False:
            count = request.args.get('count')
            count = int(count)
            for i in range(count):
                continue
            return count
        else:
            count = request.args.get('count')
            redirect_str = "http://172.17.0.3:3333?count=" + count
            return redirect(redirect_str, code=302)


api.add_resource(Greeting, '/')  # Route_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', '3333')
```

I want to be able to wait for the response back from the server 172.17.0.3 and once I receive the message, send the response back to the client. Can anyone tell me how it can be done?

Comment: What does the Server Error message say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a request to the other container instead of redirect to it if you want to wait for its response. Using e.g. the `requests` library this would look something like

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://172.17.0.3:3333?count=' + count)

return resp.text
```

Check `request`'s Quickstart guide for more info: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart.

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answers so others can find it? :)